# Can the message dialog add more icon?

Tags: java

Can the message dialog display more icon such as 2 image pop-up.
i want to know that can we add more icon at message dialog. If yes how to set it and what the code of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "message dialog?" You mean a Swing JOptionPane or JDialog? Be specific.

Comment: yes, joptionpane.showmessagedialog

Comment: Please get in the habit of searching for answers before posting your question.

Comment: what if add 2 another image jpeg?how it work?